# What is the history of this Kali form of Lord Shyama-sundara?

Tags: temple

[image][image]

Ths Shyama-sundara mandir of Khardaha, West Bengal was establised by Sri Virabhadra, the son of Sri Nityananda Mahaprabhu.The beautiful idol is believed to be carved out of a black basalt on which Sri Krishna stood during the Rajasuya jajna of Yudhisthira (https://www.speakingtree.in/discussion/pilgrimagesri-shyamsunder-mandir-khardah-wb)

What is the history of Lord Shyamasundara being worshipped as Goddess Kali as shown in the image?

Answer (score 1):

There is a leela about Krishna-Kali Roopa of Sri Shyamsundar. I do not remember the source, but this leela is well-known in Vrindavan too, and is recounted in the legend of Krishna-Kali Temple of Vrindavan.

Once Srimati Radharani was enjoying the mellows of Divine Love with Sri Keshava, when Kutila, the sister-in-law of Sri Radhika, complained to Ayan Ghosh that his wife was saluting with Sri Krishna. 
When Ayan went to check the truth for himself, Sri Krishna told Srimati Radha to quickly gather some flowers and assume a worshipping posture, while Sri Krishna transformed into the form Sri Krishna Kali. 
So, when Ayan reached the spot, he found Sri Radha devotedly worshipping Jagadambika Kalika, the Ishta Devi of Ayan himself. The latter was pleased at the sight and left. 
This is the Divine Leela of Sri Krishna assuming the form of Krishna-Kali, which is celebrated on the day of Dipavali at Sri Radha Shyamsundar Mandir in Sripat Khardah.

Comment: Radha was never married IIRC

Comment: She was. As per Brahma Vaivarta Purana, She was married to Lord Krishna. Her shadow form was married to Ayan. According to the Goswamis of Vrindavan, Radha Krishna were married thrice. And Their shadow forms were married to each other (Ayan and Chhaya Radha) to establish the Paramour Bhakti Ras.